# Coerce each row in data frame to have same center and range

Tags: r, dataframe, range, center

I am trying to find a function to coerce each row in a data frame to have the same center and range. For instance, for the mtcars dataset:

```
head(mtcars)
```

I would like each row to have a center of something around

```
mean(as.matrix(as.data.frame(mtcars)))
```

And for each row to have the same range.

I have seen the scale() function (http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.com/2012/03/r-tutorial-series-centering-variables.html), but that seems to work on columns (not rows) and seems to center on a per column basis.

Comment: Do you want each row a different center (proper to the row) or the center is the mean of all element of the matrix?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thank you, and sorry for the slow response. I want to take the mean of all element of the matrix, as in mean(as.matrix(as.data.frame(mtcars))).

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: Oh, I see how my question was confusing. Even though I wrote the syntax to get the mean of the entire matrix, I then said I did not want to use scale() because it does columns (not rows). Well, I hope my comment above cleared it up. Thanks again!

Comment: beware that the example you give with mtcars is not relevant: there are boolean in the data.frame. By the way what do oyu mean by "each row with the same range". Sorry but it is still very unclear with mtcars example. A minimal and simpler example data.frame of your choice would be better to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thanks for your input. Is there a boolean in mtcars data.frame? When I do str(mtcars), I just get 11 num types. What could explain the difference between what you see and what I see, I wonder? I would want to center each row to be the mean of all data in mtcars (which when I used the syntax I listed above, I get a value of 39.60853). Then, I want to squash each row so that all rows have the same maximum value and the same minimum value (and of course the same mean value).

Comment: I realize that the raw values in some rows will not even contain the mean value, and so they must really be manipulated to do so. I am not sure if there is some standardized way to do something like that?

Comment: just look at column vs and am of mtcars data.frame ... these are boolean. It does not make sense to take the mean of a whole data.frame containing bananas and tomatoes ...